# chrome extension content script – detect when current content ends

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanna collect data (amount of clicks, scroll distance etc.) in the content script. Is there a way to pass the moment when the content script is replaced by a new one (new site call by the user?) to send all the colelcted data as one object to the background?

I wanna prevent to send each time a message to the background when I collect new data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Content scripts live for as long as the web page they run in so you may use `unload` event on `window`, but it's not 100% reliable AFAIK so you might want to send the data on any detected activity.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. So when I detect the scroll behavior of the user I have to send the data each time the user scrolls a pixel?

Comment: Yes, or postpone using *debounce* technique.